# How to print group name once and members below the group name from multiple CSVs

Tags: bash, csv, awk

The below is my code which pulls from multiple CSVs and prints the group name and its members that logged in.

`cat *csv | awk '{print $3,$4}' > /output/userreport.txt`
the issue is that it is printing out the group name multiple times

***This is the current output example***
John, Marketing
Bob, Marketing
Ron, Marketing
Todd, Finance
Tim, Finance

***The desired output would be***
Marketing
John
Bob
Ron

Finance
Todd
Tim

Comment: Check your code - `echo.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.csv` content be

```
A, B, John, Marketing
C, D, Bob, Marketing
E, F, Ron, Marketing
G, H, Todd, Finance
I, J, Tim, Finance
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=", "}{if(group!=$4){group=$4;print $4};print $3}' file.csv
```

output

```
Marketing
John
Bob
Ron
Finance
Todd
Tim
```

Explanation: I instruct `awk` to treat space-comma as field separator (`FS`) then if group is different than last seen (or empty string if nothing was processed yet) print group name. For every line print content of 3rd column.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. any recommendations on how to how to double space after the group name and add a colon after the group name

Comment: @Ali in `awk` you might use space for concatenation, so if you change `print $4` to `print $4 ":"` you will get `:` after `Marketing` and after `Finance`

Comment: FYI That would behave the same way in any awk, not just gawk.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
$ awk -F"," ' { if( !($4 in a) ) { print $4 }  a[$4]++; print $3 } ' ali.txt
 Marketing
 John
 Bob
 Ron
 Finance
 Todd
 Tim
```

or still shorter form

```
awk -F"," '  !($4 in a)  { print $4 } { a[$4]++; print $3 } ' ali.txt
```